# What does an if statement check if a char pointer is put inside

Tags: c, string, pointers

I found code explaining what strstr() does on geeksforgeeks. This code shows if (p), but p is a char*. What is this actually checking?

```
int main() 
{ 
    // Take any two strings 
    char s1[] = "GeeksforGeeks"; 
    char s2[] = "for"; 
    char* p; 

    // Find first occurence of s2 in s1 
    p = strstr(s1, s2); 

    // Prints the result 
    if (p) { 
        printf("String found\n"); 
        printf("First occurrence of string '%s' in '%s' is '%s'", s2, s1, p); 
    } else
        printf("String not found\n"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: It's the same as `if (p != 0)`, which is basically a check for `if (p != NULL)`, which means `strstr` returned a result.

Answer (score 0):

strstr search s2 inside s1. If it present, p is different from null and contains the address of beginning of s2, and print out "String found". Otherwise print out "String not "

Comment: So does strstr() return null if the pattern is not found?

Comment: Exactly, and print out "String not found"